# Help. I installed Gnome on my computer and now i would like to uninstall it since now I have cinnamon.

Tags: gnome, uninstall

problem is i havent been able to delete it. I dont remember how I installed it but now I would just like to get rid of it.
FYI. Im using a laptop with Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

open a terminal and type the following command

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell gnome-shell-common
```

But **before you accept the changes** make sure you are not going to uninstall an application you need or want to keep in the process.

Alternatively, you can use

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell gnome-shell-common
```

to uninstall the gnome shell and remove the configuration files as well. Again, **do not accept the changes** until you have **reviewed and verified** this will not uninstall any application you need or want to keep in the process as cinnamon and gnome are closely related and may share some of the same dependencies.